# Which library sketchfab use to display the 3D models?

Tags: javascript, 3d, html5-canvas, viewer

Just wondering...

Which library sketchfab use to display the 3D models?
For example: [Link](https://sketchfab.com/models/40ab767100eb44a6be9b42d24d692ca8/embed)

HTML5 canvas of course. Looking in the code I can not understand if they use an external library or if they have written the code themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually they seem to use a custom packed library for 3D embedding (on the example link posted)

https://d2f25wgezub9nf.cloudfront.net/builds/embed-ad258a51926008151f3c.js

the editor is this custom packed file

https://d2f25wgezub9nf.cloudfront.net/builds/editor-67a44f4ae306e7bd78a3.js
and the viewer is this custom packed file

https://d2f25wgezub9nf.cloudfront.net/builds/fallbackGeneratorViewer-387bdce98e18a6654652.js

page source code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            window['webpackManifest'] = JSON.parse('{
"0":"0-1c967b67206c448cd138.js",
"1":"1-0d297699ce16c718e4aa.js",
"2":"2-05aa8ecb5962ae8dbd5d.js",
"3":"3-429e7e43701ea9b55d25.js",
"5":"5-0204c61b5399fe84f239.js",
"6":"6-763c822a0a2d726a0036.js",
"11":"11-1104121b7a7583fcc8a5.js",
"12":"viewer-e459b42392a044580f6f.js",
"13":"website-513858c9e68720acb02c.js","14":"home-18d7ffed32631755f16e.js",
"15":"editor-67a44f4ae306e7bd78a3.js",
"16":"embed-ad258a51926008151f3c.js",
"17":"playlists-fff084b1baac932dd5f2.js",
"18":"fallbackGeneratorViewer-387bdce98e18a6654652.js"}');
<script src="https://d2f25wgezub9nf.cloudfront.net/builds/commons-7433f95ed304266e4ba3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d2f25wgezub9nf.cloudfront.net/builds/embed-ad258a51926008151f3c.js"></script>
        </script>
```

[image]

Moreover sketchfab uses its own 3D viewer (https://d2f25wgezub9nf.cloudfront.net/api/sketchfab-viewer-1.0.0.js) as seen in https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sketchfab#Technology) sketchfab uses its own 3D viewer library based on the [OSG.JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSG.JS) JavaScript library

These should answer your question

Comment: Do You know any alternative? I'm testing Three.js , it is ok but much less funcional :(

Comment: There are many 3D javascript libraries out there, Three.js is one of the most complete in terms of features and extendability.

Comment: Note to viewers, the library link in the answer above leads to a porn site. Gave me quite a shock

Comment: @Dezze, ok removed the link. Thanks for pointing out!